# VBA code to run a rule from a Module

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a module and I need to run a rule.

```
Sub RunRuleMyRule()
    Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules.Item("myRuleName").Execute
End Sub
```

This works in `ThisOutlookSession` without any problem.

But I need to call "RunRuleMyRule" from my module **OR** I need to change something so the module will recognize Application.Session....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the [moduleName].[subName] function to the rule, not just a sub name to call when the rule is triggered.

Also you can remove the Application property from the code, so the following code should work in other modules:

```
Sub RunRuleMyRule()
   Session.DefaultStore.GetRules.Item("myRuleName").Execute
End Sub
```

See [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Comment: Will our execute if the rule is disabled?

Comment: The debugger is your best friend in such case.

Comment: Outlook keeps crashing when I debug

Comment: Try to break the line of code declaring each property or method on a separate line of code. Thus, you will be able to find the exact ptoperty or method which causes the issue.

Comment: Is there anyway to only apply the rule if the message is 2 weeks old

Comment: You may check it in the VBA code and process the message further or just return the control flow (don't do anything).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you try to reference the application, because it might not be recognized outside of the `ThisOutlookSession` which is a class module.

Try something like this :

```
Dim oOk As Outlook.Application

On Error Resume Next
Set oOk = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Set oOk = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

oOk.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules.Item("myRuleName").Execute
```

Comment: The shortcuts are accessible from modules.